# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n - 1}$ is convergent and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n - 1} < 2$.

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n - 1}$ is convergent and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n - 1} < 2$.

I'm not sure, but I suppose that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n - 1} < \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} = 2$$

I don't know how can I prove it exactly, but we have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n - 1} = 1+ \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{15}+... \\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} = 1+ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8}+...$$

Because

$$1 \le 1 \\ \frac{1}{3} < \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{7} < \frac{1}{4} \\ \frac{1}{15} < \frac{1}{8} \\ \mbox{and so on}$$

we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n - 1} = 1+ \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{15}+... <  1+ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8}+... = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}$$

Could you tell me, does it work? Maybe exist more formal proof?

Answer (score 3):

Notice that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=2$$
and the result follows since
$$\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\geq \frac{1}{2^{n}-1}\iff 2^{n-1}\geq1,\; \forall n\geq1\quad\text{which's true}$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a formalization of your proof
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n-1}
=1+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n-1}
=1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{n+1}-1}
<1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}=2
$$

Answer (score 1):

This does work. Since your series is positive, the comparison test you've imployed ($2^{n-1}\leq 2^n-1$, hence $\frac{1}{2^n-1}\leq\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$) implies that the sequence of partial sums of our series is increasing and bounded from above by the sequence $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\to 2$, hence convergent and also bounded by $2$. The strict inequality can be seen starting from the second element, as you've said.